# Resize post's thumbnail

Tags: wordpress

I have enabled thumbnails for my posts, so now I can add featured images.

I can get this image's ID with:

```
$id = get_post_thumbnail_id($page->ID)
```

How can I resize this image to the specified size and get its new URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the post thumbnail to the predefined sizes set by wordpress like this:

```
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail_size' );
$url = $thumb['0'];
```

Where "thumbnail_size" is you can specify any thumbnail sizes registered. You could also do a custom size like this:

```
 $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array(100,200) );
 $url = $thumb['0'];
```

You can then retrieve the image by:

```
<?=$url?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: But `the_post_thumbnail` gets global `$post` variable and I need to get thumbnail of given ID. However this function returns also whole HTML code which is useless for me.

Comment: try the above insteead

Comment: Second example returns an array with following data: `array (size=4)
  0 => string 'http://wordpress.localhost/content/uploads/2013/08/rsa-qe-04-lo.original-150x150.jpg' (length=84)
  1 => int 100
  2 => int 100
  3 => boolean true` so it does not resizes image at all.

Comment: In my custom template. I fetch post's siblings and I have to display their thumbnails. `url` contains path to `150x150` file, not `100x100`.

Comment: i am just referring to whats posted here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail